# const qualifier for pointers to pointers

Tags: c

I'm having a bit trouble deducing what is const, when applied to pointers to pointers, etc.
i.e., what is const when you have

```
 const Foo **foo;
```

Can I here change something in **foo ? as in `foo[0]->bar = 12;`

What about:

```
 const Foo ***foo;
 Foo **const foo;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) to understand what a C declaration means.

```
const int **foo;
declare foo as pointer to pointer to const int
```

thus you can change pointers, but not the value they're pointing to.

```
int * const * const foo;
declare foo as const pointer to const pointer to int
```

this, instead, is a cosnt pointer, pointing to a const pointer, to a non-const int: you cannot change pointed value, but it can be changed.

---

C uses the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), in a case where you have only modifiers at the left side of the variable (of foo) you read stuff going from right to left:

```
int(5) *(4) const(3) *(2) const(1) foo;
```

`foo` is a constant(1) pointer(2) to constant(3) pointer(4) to an integer(5).

```
int(6) const(5) *(4) const(3) *(2) const(1) foo;
const(6) int(5) *(4) const(3) *(2) const(1) foo; // [same as above]
```

In this case `foo` is a constant(1) pointer(2) to constant(3) pointer(4) to a constant(5) integer(6) [or to an integer(5) which is constant(6)].

Answer (score 3):

The `const` applies to the expression `**foo`; thus, `foo` and `*foo` are writable, but `**foo` is not.

Some other examples:

```
const Foo * const *foo;  // foo is writable, *foo and **foo are not
Foo * const * foo;       // foo and **foo are writable, *foo is not
Foo * const * const foo; // **foo is writable, foo and *foo are not
const Foo * const * const foo; // none of the expressions are writable
```

Answer (score 1):

`const Foo * * foo` (or `Foo const * * foo`) is a pointer to a pointer to a const Foo.

`Foo * const * foo` is a pointer to a const pointer to a Foo.

`Foo * * const foo` is a const pointer to a pointer to a Foo.

Comment: @sje: const Foo *const *const foo;

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to write such type expressions, I think, is to have the `const` always apply to the left. The one you gave can also be written:

```
Foo const**foo;
```

Here the `const` only applies to what is left, thus `Foo`.

```
Foo *const* foo;
```

Here on the left is `Foo*`

```
Foo const*const* foo;
```

is then `((Foo const)*const)*`.

When you in turn want to read such an expression, interchange the `const` and the bare type if necessary to have the `const` on the right.

Comment: This is how I write my code, const is always on the right. `Foo const foo`. `Foo const *foo`. `Foo *const foo`.

Answer (score 0):

In `const Foo **foo`, it's the actual `Foo` object which is const. So you can change `foo`, and you can change `*foo`, but you can't change `**foo`.

For `const Foo ***foo`, you can change `foo`, `*foo` and `**foo`, but not `***foo`.

For `Foo **const foo`, you can change `*foo` and `**foo`, but not `foo` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Read types from the inside out. Starting from `foo`, `const Foo **foo;` reads `*` (pointer) to a `*` (pointer) to `const Foo` (a Foo object you're not allowed to modify). `Foo **const foo;` reads `const` (non-modifiable) `*` (pointer) to `*` (pointer) to `Foo` (a Foo object).