# Aliasing to an array

Tags: c++

I have an object that has an array attribute, say `(*obj).some_array;`, where some_array is an integer array.

I know that we can alias simply like so:

```
int test = 10;
int &alias = test;
```

However, how can I alias to an array of an object, similarly to above but for obj's some_array?

Answer (score 7):

If `obj->some_array` is of type `int[LEN]` you can just do:

```
int (&alias)[LEN] = obj->some_array;
```

To understand this *weird* syntax you could use the[Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), a way you could read declarations you're not familiar it ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246445/const-qualifier-for-pointers-to-pointers/4246477#4246477)).

`int &alias[LEN]` (which is the same as `int &(alias[LEN])` would be an array of `LEN` references to int.
`int (&alias)[LEN]` is, instead, a reference to an array of `LEN` ints

---

Note that what you call *alias* is called a *reference* in C++!

Comment: C's declaration syntax is not driven by the Clockwise/Spiral rule. Complex declarators are built up in a logical and consistent way from simpler declarators. The clockwise / spiral rule is an aide-memoire that some people (not me!) use to help them interpret complex declarations. The rationale is to have a declaration syntax that mirrors usage. It helps especially to get array bounds the correct way around in multidimensional arrays. Your answer makes it seem like the syntax was devised to make use of an arbitrary rule just for the sake of it.

Comment: Yes, while it may initially seem counter-intuitive I think it helps to show that there is some logic behind the syntax. Just for info, here's where I last explained ["declaration follows usage"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371898/is-int-array32-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-32-ints-or-an-array-of-32-pointers-to/1371931#1371931) . Or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-expressions) .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some_array is an integer array:

```
int *alias = obj.some_array;
```

Comment: What @Oli Charlesworth said. Besides the thing your `alias` points to is not of the same type of `obj.some_array`, since `obj.some_array` is an `int[LEN]`, while `*alias` is an `int`.