# const cast and pointers to pointers

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double pointer const-correctness warnings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055655/double-pointer-const-correctness-warnings-in-c)

Why does the cases number 1, 2 and 3 works fine in C++, but not number 4 ?

```
//1
char* p1;
const char* p2 = p1;

//2
char** p3;
char * const * p4 = p3;

//3
char** p5;
const char* const * p6 = p5;

//4
char** p7;
const char** p8 = p7;
```

Comment: See [const qualifier for pointers to pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246445/const-qualifier-for-pointers-to-pointers)

Comment: [Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → Foo const**?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17)

Comment: Praetorian, maybe you could post I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See C++ FAQ - [[18.17] Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → Foo const**?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.17)

Comment: Link is dead.
[Mirror](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

May wanted to do this instead:

```
//4
typedef char** PPCHAR; 
PPCHAR p7;
const PPCHAR p8 = p7;
```

In the original form, the compiler blames about loosing const-qualification (well yes,  a pointer-to-pointer-of a constant-char is loosing const qualification when being converted to pointer-to-pointer-of a non-const-char), but if you typedef them that way you will give the precedence of interpretation the way you probably were intending initially.

Comment: he has clearly mentioned about the constness!

Comment: `const PPCHAR` is equivalent to `char** const`.  It is not the same as `const char**`

Comment: @sarat: no, in the original p8, "const char" is the fundamental type. Ali used "char". **p8='a' should be an error.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, BenjaminLindley: Well, yes you are right (Updated in the description)